# mysql query to get items from 3 types

Tags: sql, mariadb, sql-order-by, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

i have a mysql table with 3 types of data (Text, image, video) $type column holds the type of the data. (type = 1 for text, 2 for image and 3 for video)

previously i am just getting 18 records in orderby its postion

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_news WHERE news_status=1 AND show_timeline = 1 ORDER BY position DESC LIMIT $start, 18
```

Now my requirement is need to get 18 records from the table like which it should have 6 texts, 6 images and 6 videos with paging support.

output should be
(Text,Image,Video,Text,Image,Video,Text,Image,Video,Text,Image,Video,Text,Image,Video,Text,Image,Video)

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions for this:

```
select *
from (
    select n.*, row_number() over(partition by type order by position desc) rn 
    from tbl_news n
    where news_status = 1 and show_timeline = 1 
) n
where rn <= 5
order by rn, type
```

In earlier versions, one (rather inefficient) method uses a subquery:

```
select n.*
from tbl_news n
where 
    news_status = 1 
    and show_timeline = 1 
    and (
        select count(*) 
        from tbl_news n1 
        where 
            n1.type = n.type 
            and n1.news_status = n.news_status 
            and n1.show_timeline = n.show_timeline
            and n1.position <= n.position
    ) <= 5
```

Comment: My Server version: 10.1.44-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: @binuj - 10.2 has `ROW_NUMBER()`, etc.  Time to upgrade.

Comment: @binuj: Until you upgrade... I updated my answer with a solution for earlier versions.